# ¿A qué nombres se le dice Luli o Lule?

Tags: diminutivos

Siempre creía que Lule o Luli era un diminutivo para aquellas que se llamaban Lourdes, pero hace poco vi en internet que se usa también para las que se llaman Lucía. Hay algún otro nombre para los que se usen este diminutivo? Lucrecia? Luciana?

¿A qué nombres se le dice Luli o Lule, es a cualquiera que empiece con Lu?

Answer (score 1):

Según el listado de hipocorísticos en español femeninos de [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Hipocor%C3%ADsticos_en_espa%C3%B1ol):

- Lourdes — **Luli**, Lulú, Lula
- Lucía — Lu, Luci, Luchi, Lucha, **Luli**, Lula
- Lucila — Lu, Luchi, Lucha, **Luli**, Lula, Luchita
- Luján — **Luli**, Lulú, Luji

No hay Lule pero sí Lulú

Comment: Joder, hombre, no sabia que mi esposo podría ser un Alvarin. jajja

Comment: A mi tampoco me gustan las dos opciones de mi nombre, y en distintas épocas de mi vida me han dicho o siguen diciendo una de ellas 

Comment: Tengo una amiga que se llama Fernanda y le dicen "Luli" desde pequeña. No sé si es algo común para otras personas con su mismo nombre, pero lo menciono porque en estas cosas no hay reglas excluyentes.